# Why when I click one link is it executing the function for all of my links? (Javascipt)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, filter, hyperlink

When I click on the link for "id2", it executes the filter function for every link, ending with "id5" as the visible filtered list on my page.

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {

var a = document.getElementById("id1");
  var b = document.getElementById("id2");
  var c = document.getElementById("id3");
  var d = document.getElementById("id4");
  var e = document.getElementById("id5");
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("className")

    
  a.onclick = filter(a.id);
  b.onclick = filter(b.id);
  c.onclick = filter(c.id);
  d.onclick = filter(d.id);
  e.onclick = filter(e.id);

  
  function filter(tag) {
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
        if (tag === "view all") {
            x[i].style.display = "block";
        }   
        else {
             if (tag.toLowerCase() === x[i].getAttribute('alt').toLowerCase()) 
        x[i].style.display = "block";
      else
        x[i].style.display = "none";
        
        }
    return false;
    }
  
}
```

The top part where I have set up my links appears as follows:

```
<a href="" id="id1" rel="history" class="active">View All</a>
<a href="" id="id2" class="active">ID 2</a>
<a href="" id="id3" class="active">ID 3</a>
<a href="" id="id4" class="active">ID 4</a>
<a href="" id="id5" class="active">ID 5</a>
```

The filter works correctly, the only issue is that it is executing the function for all links!

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Please create a [mre]. I'm also wondering that clicks do anything at all, because `a.onclick = filter(a.id);` is wrong; it's `a.onclick = () => filter(a.id);`

Comment: the click would not do anything. all the code are already executed when window load.

Comment: A good tip: You should look into attaching listeners, then parse the event. You can then access the element through that parsed event in order to know exactly which link you pressed. `event.target`. That way, you'll have a fully dynamic function that will help you simplify your logic and avoid redundancy, such as your repeated getElementById. Attach the listener to a class instead.

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is your functions are executing as soon as you are trying to assign the event handler.
Any function with `();` after it will get executed.

You can use the concept of closures and return a new function. Use a function wrapper which returns a new function for each of your tag.

```
a.onclick = filter(a.id);
  b.onclick = filter(b.id);
  c.onclick = filter(c.id);
  d.onclick = filter(d.id);
  e.onclick = filter(e.id);

  function filterWrapper(tag) { 
  var tagValue = tag; 
 return function filter() {
    let tag = tagValue;
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
        if (tag === "view all") {
            x[i].style.display = "block";
        }   
        else {
             if (tag.toLowerCase() === x[i].getAttribute('alt').toLowerCase()) 
        x[i].style.display = "block";
      else
        x[i].style.display = "none";
        
        }
    return false;
    }
  } 
}
```

Obviously, you could have fetched the value of `id` attribute inside the function itself. `this` inside event handler belongs to the element itself.

```
 a.onclick = filter;
  b.onclick = filter;
  c.onclick = filter;
  d.onclick = filter;
  e.onclick = filter;

  
  function filter() {
   let tag = this.getAttribute('id');
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
        if (tag === "view all") {
            x[i].style.display = "block";
        }   
        else {
             if (tag.toLowerCase() === x[i].getAttribute('alt').toLowerCase()) 
        x[i].style.display = "block";
      else
        x[i].style.display = "none";
        
        }
    return false;
    }
  
}
```